# How to set MaxStepSize for spatial variable in NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations

When applying NDSolve to a 1-D transient heat equation, the following code appears to set MaxStepSize for the temporal variable t.

```
t0 = 0;
t1 = 10;
x0 = 0;
x1 = 1;
nx = 100;
dx = (x1-x0)/nx;
eqs1 = {D[u[x,t],x,x] - D[u[x,t],t] == NeumannValue[1, x==x0 || x == x1], DirichletCondition[u[x,t]==0, t== t0]};
sol1 = NDSolve[eqs1, u, {x, x0, x1}, {t, t0, t1}, Method-> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t}, MaxStepSize -> dx]
f = u /. First[sol1];
Dimensions[f["Grid"]]
```

I would like to apply MaxStepSize to the spatial variable x, rather than to the temporal variable t.

I've tried without success variations involving SpatialDiscretization, such as

```
NDSolve[eqs1, u, {x, x0, x1}, {t, t0, t1}, Method-> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, "SpatialDiscretization"-> {"TensorProductGrid","MaxStepSize" -> dx}}]
```

which yields the following error:

> NDSolve::moptx: Method option MaxStepSize in {NDSolve`FiniteElement,MaxStepSize->1/100} is not one of {ConstraintMethod,BoundaryTolerance,InterpolationOrder,IntegrationOrder,LinearSolveMethod,MeshOptions,PrecomputeGeometryData}. >>

What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for `MaxCellMeasure` in case of the finite element method.

```
t0 = 0;
t1 = 10;
x0 = 0;
x1 = 1;
nx = 100;
dx = (x1 - x0)/nx;
eqs1 = {D[u[x, t], x, x] - D[u[x, t], t] == 
    NeumannValue[1, x == x0 || x == x1], 
   DirichletCondition[u[x, t] == 0, t == t0]};
sol1 = NDSolveValue[eqs1, u, {x, x0, x1}, {t, t0, t1}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}, MaxStepSize -> dx]
Dimensions[sol1["Grid"]]
```

In case of the "SpatialDiscretization" "TensorProductGrid" you are looking for a "MaxPoints" and/or "MinPoints" option. You'd also need to adjust your equation a bit like so:

```
t0 = 0;
t1 = 10;
x0 = 0;
x1 = 1;
nx = 100;
dx = (x1 - x0)/nx;
eqs1 = {D[u[x, t], x, x] - D[u[x, t], t] == 0, u[x, 0] == 0
   , Derivative[1, 0][u][0, t] == 1
   , Derivative[1, 0][u][1, t] == 1
   };
sol1 = NDSolveValue[eqs1, u, {x, x0, x1}, {t, t0, t1}, 
  Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
    "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
      "MaxPoints" -> 125, "MinPoints" -> 125}}, MaxStepSize -> dx]
Dimensions[sol1["Grid"]]
```

This is not quite correct as the initial condition does not match the boundary condition; but that's only possible with more knowledge of what you would like to solve.

Comment: Thanks. The FiniteElement approach worked, and solved my immediate problem. However,

`Method -> {"MethodOfLines", "TemporalVariable" -> t, 
  "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"TensorProductGrid", 
    "MaxPoints" -> 2000}}`

yielded the error

NDSolveValue::moptx: Method option MaxPoints in {NDSolve`FiniteElement,MaxPoints->2000} is not one of {ConstraintMethod,BoundaryTolerance,InterpolationOrder,IntegrationOrder,LinearSolveMethod,MeshOptions,PrecomputeGeometryData}. >>

Can you advise the correct syntax for the latter approach?

Comment: @RonnenLevinson, see update.

Comment: The sample system models heat conduction following the sudden application of constant surface heat flux to a body at initial temperature zero. As originally written, it defines the BCs by adding a NeumannValue[] term to the PDE, rather than by providing separate BC equations, to avoid the warning from NDSolve[] about inconsistent boundary and initial conditions. I have been unable get the TensorProductGrid flavor of SpatialDiscretization to work with a NeumannValue[]-specified BC. That, coupled with the need to control grid spacing, prompted my original question.

Comment: @RonnenLevinson, `NeumannValue` will always trigger FEM - as `NeumannValue` is FEM specific. If you want TensorProductGrid you need to express the derivatives with `Derivative` or `D`.